# flipping depth frame received from Kinect

Tags: c++, visual-c++, kinect

I use the following c++ code to read out the depth information from the kinect:

```
    BYTE * rgbrun = m_depthRGBX;
    const USHORT * pBufferRun = (const USHORT *)LockedRect.pBits;

    // end pixel is start + width*height - 1
    const USHORT * pBufferEnd = pBufferRun + (Width * Height);

    // process data for display in main window.
    while ( pBufferRun < pBufferEnd )
    {
        // discard the portion of the depth that contains only the player index
        USHORT depth = NuiDepthPixelToDepth(*pBufferRun);

        BYTE intensity = static_cast<BYTE>(depth % 256);


        // Write out blue byte
        *(rgbrun++) = intensity;

        // Write out green byte
        *(rgbrun++) = intensity;

        // Write out red byte
        *(rgbrun++) = intensity;

        ++rgbrun;

        ++pBufferRun;

    }
```

What I'd like to know is, what is the easiest way to implement frame flipping (horizontal & vertical)? I couldn't find any function in the kinect SDK, but maybe I missed it?

**EDIT1** I'd like to not having to use any external libraries, so any solutions that explain the depth data layout and how to invert rows / columns, is highly appreciated.

Comment: It depends, naturally ;-) I generally go for the row-by-row pixel-copying approach, because you can easily spread each row "copy and reverse" operation over multiple worker threads. Alternatively, if you have a graphics library that supports single channel 16bpp images, you might be able to use that to build and image and flip it. Windows' own WIC stuff should be able to do this. I don't have any examples for you though, I'm afraid, so I'll leave this as a comment instead of a proper answer.

Comment: @Rook thanks - I'd like to avoid external libraries and would rather prefer to understand the depth data layout and how to flip rows / columns.

Comment: Given that you're probably tethered to Windows already, using WIC (which is part of the standard windows library) isn't that much of a stretch. I'll see if I can cobble together a simple bit of plain C++ for you, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you're using a standard 16bpp single channel depth map with player data. This is a nice easy format to work with. An image buffer is arranged row-wise, and each pixel in the image data has the bottom 3 bits set to the player ID and the top 13 bits set to depth data.

Here's a quick'n'dirty way to read each row in reverse, and write it out to an RGBWhatever image with a simple depth visualisation that's a little nicer to look at that the wrapping output you currently use.

```
BYTE * rgbrun = m_depthRGBX;
const USHORT * pBufferRun = (const USHORT *)LockedRect.pBits;

for (unsigned int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
{
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
    {
        // shift off the player bits
        USHORT depthIn = pBufferRun[(y * Width) + (Width - 1 - x)] >> 3;

        // valid depth is (generally) in the range 0 to 4095.
        // here's a simple visualisation to do a greyscale mapping, with white
        // being closest. Set 0 (invalid pixel) to black.
        BYTE intensity = 
            depthIn == 0 || depthIn > 4095 ?
                0 : 255 - (BYTE)(((float)depthIn / 4095.0f) * 255.0f);

        *(rgbrun++) = intensity;
        *(rgbrun++) = intensity;
        *(rgbrun++) = intensity;
        ++rgbrun;
    }
}
```

Code untested, E&OE, etc ;-)

It is possible to parallelise the outer loop, if instead of using a single `rgbrun` pointer you get a pointer to the beginning of the current row and write the output to that instead.

Comment: Nope, horizontal. I'm reading the rows out in top-to-bottom order: `pBuffer[y * Width]` points to the beginning of each row. Then I'm reading each row in right-to-left order, `Width - 1 - x` being an offset between the far end of the row to the beginning of the row. To do a vertical flip as well, replace `y * Width` with `(Height - 1 - y) * Width`

Comment: (for the benefit of future viewers, the question that has since disappeared regarded the direction of flip)

Comment: and a vertical flip by itself would be `pBufferRun[((Height - 1 - y) * Width) + x]`, correct?

Comment: @memyself Yep. Easy enough to verify, anyway!